# R - how to add cases of one variable to other variable (stack variables)

Tags: r, stack, rbind

```
var1 var2 var3
   1    2    3
   1    2    3
   1    2    3
```

I want to stack var2 and var3 underneath var1 to get:

```
var1
   1
   1
   1
   2
   2
   2
   3
   3
   3
```

I tried:

```
data$var <- append(data$var1,data$var2)
```

Then I get an error that my replacement has more rows. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(var1=1:3,var2=4:6,var3=7:9)
df2 <- stack(df)
print(df2)

  values  ind
1      1 var1
2      2 var1
3      3 var1
4      4 var2
5      5 var2
6      6 var2
7      7 var3
8      8 var3
9      9 var3
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try `unlist`:

```
dtf <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 1:3, c = 1:3)
unlist(dtf)
a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2 c3 
 1  2  3  1  2  3  1  2  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Your output has a different number of rows to your input, so trying to turn the latter into the former is going to cause problems. Just make a new data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(df$var1, df$var2, df$var3)
```

You can also get fancy with `do.call`, taking advantage of the fact that a data frame is a list under the hood:

```
df <- data.frame(x = do.call("c", df))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're getting this error because each column/variable in a dataframe needs to be the same length. You could make a new longer variable and join it with the old dataframe but it is going to repeat the data in the other variables.

```
> df <- data.frame(var1=1:3,var2=4:6,var3=7:9)
> df
  var1 var2 var3
1    1    4    7
2    2    5    8
3    3    6    9

# join combination of var1/var2 and 'df' dataframe

> data.frame(newvar=c(df$var1,df$var2),df)
  newvar var1 var2 var3
1      1    1    4    7
2      2    2    5    8
3      3    3    6    9
4      4    1    4    7
5      5    2    5    8
6      6    3    6    9
```

Comment: if I do that I get: Error in data.frame(j_boa = c(data$dv_job_8_1, data$dv_job_8_2), df) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 6, 3

Comment: @user670186 The example above works, so I think there might be something wrong in your code. Maybe c(data$dv_job_8_1, data$dv_job_8_2), df) needs to be c(data$dv_job_8_1, data$dv_job_8_2), **data**) so you are referencing the correct original dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Stack seems like the obvious answer here, but `melt` in the reshape package does works in an equivalent fashion and MAY offer some flexibility for other more complicated situations. Assuming you are working with an object named dat:

```
library(reshape)
melt(dat)

  variable value
1     var1     1
2     var1     1
3     var1     1
4     var2     2
5     var2     2
6     var2     2
7     var3     3
8     var3     3
9     var3     3
```

If you need to preserve one of the columns as an ID variable:

```
> melt(dat, id.vars = "var1")
  var1 variable value
1    1     var2     2
2    1     var2     2
3    1     var2     2
4    1     var3     3
5    1     var3     3
6    1     var3     3
```