# Better way to turn two columns into one in R/Splus?

Tags: r, matrix

Currently I do the following:

```
x <- cbind(c(1, 2, 3), c(4, 5, 6))
x.merged <- matrix(t(x), ncol=1)
```

to create one column with values `1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6,` from the matrix `x`. But relying on `t(x)` seems a bit clunky. Is there a better way to do this? I'd like to avoid a for-loop or `apply` if there's a simpler built-in function that handles this sort of thing.

EDIT: To be clearer, `x` is just given to me. The first line of code above was only meant to illustrate the values involved. It might have been better for me to write:

```
> x
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    3    6
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, if you make it a vector it doesn't take more than :

```
> c(t(x))
[1] 1 4 2 5 3 6
```

Or, if you really have to avoid `t()` then you could do :

```
> c(apply(x,2,rbind))
[1] 1 4 2 5 3 6
```

This works for an arbitrary number of columns, but includes an apply. If you don't want to use that one, you'll have to manually specify all the columns you want to paste behind eachother. But the t() solution is by far the fastest :

```
> n <- 10000000    
> x <- matrix(rnorm(n),ncol=2)
> system.time(c(t(x)))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.07    0.00    0.06 

> system.time(c(rbind(x[,1],x[,2])))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.22    0.05    0.26
```

Remember that a matrix can be seen as a vector with dimensions added to it, and is always read columnwise. So you cannot really avoid the `t()` in your solution. You could always just use it as a vector, eg :

```
> x[4]
[1] 4
```

just works, as long as you remember that the matrix is read columnwise. So in your case you'll need

```
> t(x)[4]
[1] 5
```

In case you really need it as a matrix, then :

```
> matrix(t(x))
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    4
[3,]    2
[4,]    5
[5,]    3
[6,]    6
```

Comment: I'm using `c(t(x))`. Didn't even know `c()` would strip dimensions in that way! Thx for the wonderful answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think the way to do this with the fewest keystrokes is:

```
c(rbind(c(1, 2, 3), c(4, 5, 6)))
```

Using `rbind` eliminates the transpose, and `c` is the shortest way to strip attributes (including dimensions) off an object, although it's a bit of an abuse to use it this way.

Comment: just edited my question above. Since `x` is given to me, I'd have to tweak your solution to `c(rbind(x[,1], x[,2]))`

Comment: @brianjd : then you better use t(), see also my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 2**

One of the optional arguments in `matrix` is to fill by row. We can use that here and is very similar to your original solution. You can obviously swap out `ncol` for `nrow` if that suits your fancy better.

```
matrix(x, ncol = 1, byrow = TRUE)
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3
[4,]    4
[5,]    5
[6,]    6
```

I swear there was a question about this like yesterday, but I can't manage to find it. Let's see if I can remember some of the answers from that question:

```
#do.call will execute a function, "c" for combine in this case, over a list so we coerce the 
#matrix to a list
do.call("c", as.list(x))
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6


#Similar concept with stack, but it expects a data.frame 
stack(as.data.frame(x))
  values ind
1      1  V1
2      2  V1
3      3  V1
4      4  V2
5      5  V2
6      6  V2

#The melt function in package reshape can do this and a lot more when combined with "cast"
library(reshape)
melt(x)
  X1 X2 value
1  1  1     1
2  2  1     2
3  3  1     3
4  1  2     4
5  2  2     5
6  3  2     6
```

**EDIT**: Seems like I should have been able to find the question seeing as I provided an answer, but I digress: [R - how to add cases of one variable to other variable (stack variables)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482249/r-how-to-add-cases-of-one-variable-to-other-variable-stack-variables/5486140#5486140)

Comment: -1 for not answering the question - which is how to interleave values.

Comment: @Joris: not sure why `byrow = TRUE` is getting a +1. Leaving it out or setting `byrow = FALSE` explicitly will yield the EXACT same results. I took my first stab at this problem with `byrow = TRUE` and was surprised it didn't interleave the results the way I wanted. I was even more surprised that the `byrow` option seemed to have NO effect on the results.

Comment: @brianjd: byrow has no effect when there's only one column. Filling by row, with each row consuming a single value, is the same as filling by column.

Comment: @Tyler: Right, that's the clearest way of putting it. My initial confusion was in thinking that the INPUT to `matrix()` (with option `byrow=TRUE` set) was taken in by row rather than the OUTPUT being written by row.

Comment: @brianjd : You're right. I readded my earlier answer. You perfectly described my confusion. I was too quick.

Comment: @brian - I misread your question last night, sorry for the confusion. It looks like @Joris and @Hadley have supplied answers that are more on point. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
as.vector(matrix(c(1:3,4:6),byrow=T,nrow=2))
[1] 1 4 2 5 3 6
```

Comment: I edited my question above. Because `x` is given to me, I'd have to tweak your solution to read: `as.vector(matrix(c(x),byrow=T,nrow=2))`. But `c(t(x))` will do the same.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a matrix as opposed to a data frame, there's no reason not to use `t`. Note that `stack` uses `as.list` and `lapply`, so is probably less elegant in this case. However, if what you want is just a vector, you can omit the `matrix(*, ncol=1)` bit; just use `as.vector`.